# Is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$ a subfield of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$?

Tags: galois-theory

Is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$ a subfield of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$? I think that $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ since $\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$. So maybe $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$ a subfield of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$? But there are only 5 subfields of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$: $\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6})$, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ by Galois theory. I am confused. Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried seeing if $\mathbb {Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$ equals one of those 5 subfields you've listed?

Comment: $1/(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})=-\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$, so $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}\in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$

Comment: This is why being rigorous with Galois theory is important. Things may look different even though they are actually equal. Indeed, as Nirdonkey pointed out, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ even though it may not be obvious at first.

Comment: @MaxG. : your "This is why being rigorous with Galois theory is important" does not sound good...

Comment: I didn't mean it in a bad way at all, and I am not saying anything against the question asker! I didn't mean it to come off that way, it's just something my professor used to say; I just feel that this question demonstrates this point greatly.

Comment: $K(a+b) \subseteq K(a,b)$ follows immediately from the definition of $K(a,b)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $\sqrt 2+\sqrt 3\in \mathbb Q(\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3)$, you have that $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2+\sqrt 3)$ is a subfield of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3)$. But you actually have much better : $$\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2+\sqrt 3)=\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3).$$

Indeed, $$\frac{1}{\sqrt 2+\sqrt 3}=\sqrt 2-\sqrt 3\in \mathbb Q(\sqrt 2+\sqrt 3)$$
and thus
$$\sqrt 2=\frac{\sqrt 2+\sqrt 3-(\sqrt 2-\sqrt 3)}{2}\in\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2+\sqrt 3).$$ You can argue as well to prove that $\sqrt 3\in \mathbb Q(\sqrt 2+\sqrt 3)$. Therefore, $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2+\sqrt 3)$ contain $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)$ and $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 3)$ as subfield, and thus contain $$\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)\mathbb Q(\sqrt 3)=\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3)$$
as subfield. Therefore $$\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2+\sqrt 3)=\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3).$$

No need Galois theory to prove this simple fact !